# Java RMI: how can two clients communicate with their references

Tags: java, rmi

I got this homework which is to learn RMI. I need to create a server and multiple instances of clients.

Each client connects to the server and the server must keep a list of all of them. The server then return a list of network connections of all clients to every clients so they can call each other's method without having to use the server.

I got the part where each client connect to the server working. But I don't understand what to keep and what to send to the clients so they can communicate with each other.

I am currently trying to keep a list of remote References when using the servers's "registerToBank" method. Am I far from the solution ?

Thanks

Here is the current code :

**Server's interface**

```
package banqueRmiInterface;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import utils.SuccursaleInformationsContainer;

public interface BanqueRMIInterface extends Remote {
    public int registerToBank(int moneyAmount) throws RemoteException;
}
```

**Server:**

```
package banque;

import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.RemoteRef;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import banqueRmiInterface.BanqueRMIInterface;
import succursale.Succursale;
import utils.SuccursaleInformationsContainer;

public class Banque extends UnicastRemoteObject implements BanqueRMIInterface{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
int totalMoney = 0;
List<Succursale> remoteObjectList = new ArrayList<Succursale>();

protected Banque() throws RemoteException {
    super();

}

@Override
public int registerToBank(int moneyAmount, Succursale succursale) throws RemoteException{
    succursale.setId(remoteObjectList.size());
    remoteObjectList.add(succursale);
    totalMoney += moneyAmount;
    System.out.println(" succurcale #" + succursale.getId() + " added "  + moneyAmount + "$ to the lot");
    System.out.println("New total of money is: " + totalMoney);

    updateClientsRemoteObjectList();

    return remoteObjectList.size()-1;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        startRmiRegistry();

        Naming.rebind("//127.0.0.1/Bank", new Banque()); //Change this for your own ip

        System.out.println("Server ready");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Server exception: " + e.toString());
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void updateClientsRemoteObjectList(){
    for(int i = 0; i < remoteObjectList.size(); i++){
        System.out.println("updating client #" +remoteObjectList.get(i).getId() );
        remoteObjectList.get(i).updateRemoteObjectList(remoteObjectList);
    }
}


public static void startRmiRegistry(){
    try {
        java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        System.out.println("RMI registry ready.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception starting RMI registry:");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

**Clients:**

```
public class Succursale implements Serializable{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -905645444505287895L;
private BanqueRMIInterface look_up;
private int id = 0;
private List<Succursale> remoteObjectList;

public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException, NotBoundException, Exception{
    Succursale test = new Succursale();
    test.doThings();

}

public void doThings() throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException, NotBoundException, Exception{
    look_up = (BanqueRMIInterface) Naming.lookup("//127.0.0.1/Bank"); //Change this for your own ip
    System.out.println("Combien d'argent vous avez?");
    BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String userInput;
    int moneyAmount =0;
    if ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        System.out.println(userInput);
        moneyAmount = Integer.parseInt(userInput);

    }


    id = look_up.registerToBank(moneyAmount, this);

    while(true)
    {
        //do things
    }
}

public void updateRemoteObjectList(List<Succursale> remoteObjectList){
    this.remoteObjectList = remoteObjectList;
}

public int getId(){
    return this.id;
}
public void setId(int id){
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

Comment: How can every client will communicate to each other? If they communicate via RMI then you have to expose RMI interface from every client.

Comment: And what does it mean "return a list of network connections"? You can not return a network connection to a remote server so that would use in different server(different location)!

Comment: @Zico can you post your comment as an answer this was the solution that worked for me, Thanks !

Comment: @Zicco Can you tell us what on earth that actually means first?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How can every client will communicate to each other? **If they communicate via RMI then you have to expose RMI interface from every client.** And you can not return a network connection to a remote server so that would use in different server(different location)!

Comment: Final sentence is very hard to understand but fundamentally incorrect. An RMI stub essentially *is* a 'connection to a remote server', or at least the means of doing so, and doesn't magically change its target location: and the rest of it doesn't follow from the first part.

Comment: Last sentence was actually a statement of this part of question "The server then return a list of network connections of all clients to every clients so they can call each other's method without having to use the server." I am not sure how can this is fundamentally incorrect?

Answer (score -1):

The answer is in your title. 'With their references'. All a client has to to is get a remote reference to another client from the server, and then just start using it in the normal way.

Firewalls permitting.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for answering. Could you please elaborate ? I am very lost at the moment. I tried changing the client so it create an object of itself then pass "this" to the server. But when the server tries to call method from the client objects he kept. the changes does not appear on the clients but on the object of the client he kept... will update code in the question

Comment: Or am I completely wrong and you have to register every client to the rmi registry so they can call each other ?

Comment: The client has to export itself as a remote object that implements a remote interface, same as the server does. At present your client is merely Serializable, which transports it bodily to the server. You don't need to do anything with the RMI Registry.